# How do I enable performance logging for a launchd service?

Tags: launchd

I want to use `launchctl runstats my-service`. When I run it I get

```bash
$ launchctl runstats gui/501/my-service
Performance logging is not enabled.
```

I couldn't find anything on the internet related to this command.

Comment: What version of Mac OS are you running? The man page for ```launchctl``` on 10.15.7 does not mention a "runstats" subcommand, although ```strings `which launchctl` | fgrep runstats``` finds it, and ```launchctl runstats``` answers ```Usage: launchctl runstats <service-target>```. So, at best, it's an undocumented subcommand.

Comment: I'm running macOS Monterey 12.4 (21F79)

Comment: do you know of another way to see the CPU used by an agent over time?

Answer (score 1):

I add the following code in plist

```
 <key>StandardOutPath</key>
 <string>/tmp/frp/logfile.log</string>
 <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
 <string>/tmp/frp/err_logfile.log</string>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already had this added to my plist, but it didn't enable me to see performance logging. I don't think the stderr and stdout config has anything to do with performance logging